# Using Cursor to Create Login and Temporary Password

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get the cursor to create logins, passwords, and usernames for names in a table. I have everything working correctly except the temporary password, which is the first four of the login name with 9999 tacked on the end. I've coded that correctly (i think), but I'm having trouble getting that to work when creating the login. It's pulling in '@Password' as the password instead of BBro999. I know it's because I have '''@Password''' for the password, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to code this to where it will pull in 'BBro999' as @Password.

```
USE AP

DECLARE
    @CreateLogin    varchar(256),
    @LoginName      varchar(20),
    @Password       char(20);

DECLARE Login_Cursor CURSOR
    Dynamic

FOR

SELECT DISTINCT*
    FROM NewLogins;

OPEN Login_Cursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM Login_Cursor INTO @LoginName;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN
    SET @Password = LEFT(@LoginName, 4) + '9999';
    SET @CreateLogin = 'CREATE LOGIN ' + @LoginName + ' ' + 'WITH PASSWORD = ' + '''@Password'''+ ','+ ' ' + 'DEFAULT_DATABASE = AP';

EXEC (@CreateLogin);

SET @CreateLogin = 'CREATE USER ' + @LoginName + ' ' + 'FOR LOGIN ' + @LoginName;

EXEC (@CreateLogin);

SET @CreateLogin = 'ALTER ROLE PaymentEntry ADD MEMBER ' + @LoginName;

EXEC (@CreateLogin);

FETCH NEXT FROM Login_Cursor
    INTO @LoginName;

END;

CLOSE Login_Cursor;

DEALLOCATE Login_Cursor;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
    SET @CreateLogin = 'CREATE LOGIN ' + @LoginName + ' ' + 'WITH PASSWORD = ''' + @Password+ ''','+ ' ' + 'DEFAULT_DATABASE = AP';
```

Or

```
    SET @CreateLogin = 'CREATE LOGIN ' + @LoginName + ' ' + 'WITH PASSWORD = ' + quotename(@Password, '''') +','+ ' ' + 'DEFAULT_DATABASE = AP';
```

The password should be quoted, not the variable

Comment: Fantastic! I can't believe I didn't think to move the quotes somewhere else. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
  SET @CreateLogin = 'CREATE LOGIN ' + @LoginName + ' ' + 'WITH PASSWORD = ' + 
  @Password+ ','+ ' ' + 'DEFAULT_DATABASE = AP';
```

Use quotation same as used for @loginname

Try select or Print statement to look up what is actual string stored in @createlogin

Select @Createlogin
Or
Print @Createlogin